# How can I log the value of an input?

Tags: javascript

I've been importing an input by its ID from index.html to main.js. When I run `console.log(input name)` I get null, but when I log `typeof` it returns "object". How I can log the value?

```js
let price = document.getElementById('price');
let tax = document.getElementById('tax');
let ads = document.getElementById('ads');
let discount = document.getElementById('discount');
let total = document.getElementById('total');
let amount = document.getElementById('amount');
let category = document.getElementById('category');
let create = document.querySelector('#create');
console.log()


function totalint() {
  if (price != '') {
    let result = (+price.value + +tax.value + +ads.value) - +discount.value;
    total.innerHTML = result;
  }
}
```

Comment: `null` is of the type `object`.

Comment: Are you just asking how to retrieve the value of an input? I think you've distracted from the primary issue by mentioning logs so much.

Comment: The problem you have is likely because your `document.getElementById` is executed before the element your are looking for exists in the DOM.

Comment: Please expand the snippet demo above to show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the code before the page load completing, please use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      let price = document.getElementById('test');
    // Log to console
    console.log(price)
});
```